# Find and replace only last character of regex match using notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have this regex I am using for Replace All in notepad++

`[0-9]+\.`

This matches any numbers followed by period.

Now I wish to keep the digits as they are and only replace the period by a comma.

For example,

23.234 is changed to 23,234

Comment: There are many, many duplicates to this question.

Comment: You can replace matches of `(?<=[0-9])\.` with a comma as the same periods would be matched by `(?<=[0-9]+)\.` if variable-length positive lookbehinds were supported.

Comment: Would you like to format this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

This would require the use of groups.
For example

([0-9]). matches all periods after digits.
Replace by $1,

23.234 is changed to 23,234